# Adding Multiple Durations in Javascript

Tags: javascript

There were a few old solutions, most using jQuery, on adding multiple durations. I didn't find them to work correctly, so I wrote this one below. I'm not the best at JS, so I thought some input would be helpful on whether there is any issue with this script or a more efficient way to achieve the same result. I'm basically looking to add an array of times together for a total time, displayed correctly with two digits for the minutes and seconds. If nothing else, maybe this will help someone else.

```js
var Playlist = ["5:00:00", "7:00", ":05"];

function TimeAdd(array) {
    let h = 0;
    let m = 0;
    let s = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < Playlist.length; i++) {
        let timeArray = array[i].split(":");
        if(timeArray.length == 3){
            h += parseInt(timeArray[0]);
            m += parseInt(timeArray[1]);
            s += parseInt(timeArray[2]);}
        if(timeArray.length == 2 && timeArray[0]!==""){
            m += parseInt(timeArray[0]);
            s += parseInt(timeArray[1]);}
        if(timeArray.length == 1){
            s += parseInt(timeArray[0]); }
        if(timeArray[0]==""){
            s += parseInt(timeArray[1]);}
}
let time = s + (m * 60) + (h * 3600);
let hoursDec = time / 60 / 60;
let hours = Math.trunc(hoursDec);
let minutesDec = (hoursDec - hours) * 60;
let minutes = Math.trunc(minutesDec);
let seconds = Math.round((minutesDec - minutes) * 60);
    
console.log(hours + ":" + minutes.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2}) + ":" + seconds.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2}));}
```

Comment: You received several answers, but did not mark one as accepted. Is there none that suits your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I would just convert them all to seconds using reduce.

```js
var playlist = ["5:00:00", "7:00", "5"];

function getSeconds(time) {
  var parts = ("0:0:" + time).split(":").slice(-3)
  return parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 + parseInt(parts[2], 10);
}

var totalSeconds = playlist.reduce((acc, ts) => acc + getSeconds(ts),0);

function secondsToHms(secs) {
    var h = ("0" + Math.floor(secs / 3600)).substr(-2);
    var m = ("0" + Math.floor(secs % 3600 / 60)).substr(-2);
    var s = ("0" + Math.floor(secs % 3600 % 60)).substr(-2);
    return h + ":" + m + ":" + s; 
}

console.log(secondsToHms(totalSeconds));
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar way, I would convert the `playlist` array to seconds and print the number with the mask you need:

In case your array can be formatted as: `["05:00:00", "00:07:00", "00:00:05"]` (so with a mask of `##:##:##`:

```js
var playlist = ["5:00:00", "00:07:00", "00:00:05"];

var mask = [3600, 60, 1];
var seconds = playlist.reduce((a,b) => a + b.split(':').map((v,i) => parseInt(v) * mask[i]).reduce((x,y) => x+y,0), 0);

console.log(new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8));
```

Otherwise either optimize the `reduce` function to be able to process the formatting variations you care about or convert your formatting to the original mask `##:##:##` and continue with the algorithm.

UPDATE: Based on @epascarello, the optimizations to `reduce` function can be done using:

```js
var playlist = ["05:00:00", "7:00", ":05"];

var mask = [3600, 60, 1];
var seconds = playlist.reduce(
  (a, b) => a + ("0:0:" + b.replace(/^\:/g, ""))
                            .split(':')
                            .slice(-3)
                            .map((v, i) => parseInt(v) * mask[i])
                            .reduce(
                              (x, y) => x + y,
                              0), 
  0);

console.log(new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8));
```

This one works with all your formatting conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to convert to seconds is good. It is however a pity that your function treats the different lengths of the `split` result as separate cases. This leads to unnecessary code repetition. You can replace that `if..else if` block with a call to `reduce`.

Here is how it could work:

```js
const toSeconds = dur =>
    dur.split(":").reduce((a, b) => a*60 + +b, 0);

const toDuration = secs => [
        Math.floor(secs / 3600),
        Math.floor(secs / 60) % 60,
        secs % 60
    ].join(":").replace(/:(\d)\b/g, ":0$1");
    
const addDurations = durations => toDuration(
    durations.map(toSeconds).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
);

// demo
let duration = addDurations(["5:00:00", "7:00", ":05"]);
console.log(duration);
```